# How do I propagate the --debug= setting to a nested makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So I have a custom Makefile nested/launched from my main Makefile (automake Makefile.am if it matters).

If I have an include dependency or other rule issue in the main Makefile, I can just append `--debug=b` to `make` to see what the issue is, occasionally `--debug=a` is my choice of hammer.

However, that setting does not "magically" get passed on to the nested custom Makefile, and, of course, that is where my problems always seem to be (we all know automake is perfect...).

Is there some way that I can access the current setting of `--debug=` from within a Makefile or otherwise propagate the value of `--debug=` into the call on the nested Makefile?

It is often non-trivial for me to call the nested Makefile directly as it already takes a lot of environment from the main Makefile, which is sometimes relevant to the issue being debugged.

On the basis that perhaps such flags /should/ /be/ passed through the make engine, this is somewhat like the rule I am using to pass through:

```
all-local:
    @echo Make custom with $(MY_PRODUCT_CLOUD_ENABLEMENT) $(MY_PRODUCT_PROTECT_ENABLEMENT) $(ACL_ENABLEMENT) CPPEXTRA="$(CPPEXTRA)" $(FIPS_ENABLEMENT) CPPMORE="$(CPPMORE)" $(MY_PRODUCT_PROTECT_CPPEXTRA_ENABLEMENT) $(ACL_CPPEXTRA_ENABLEMENT)
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $(MY_PRODUCT_CLOUD_ENABLEMENT) $(MY_PRODUCT_PROTECT_ENABLEMENT) $(ACL_ENABLEMENT) $(FIPS_ENABLEMENT) $(MY_PRODUCT_ENABLEMENT) -f Makefile.product CPPEXTRA="$(CPPEXTRA)" CPPMORE="$(CPPMORE)"  $(MY_PRODUCT_PROTECT_CPPEXTRA_ENABLEMENT) $(ACL_CPPEXTRA_ENABLEMENT)
```

Comment: Flags like `-d` etc. **ARE** passed from parent make invocations to sub-make invocations.  If you're not seeing this then something in your makefile is causing this to not work and we can't help without seeing how you are invoking the sub-make.

Comment: @MadScientist Just for you, I have appended the relevant chunk

Comment: Well, without seeing the actual make command line it's hard to say since we have no idea what those variables expand to.  However, the way make flags are passed to sub-makes is via the `MAKEFLAGS` environment variable.  You can read about it in the manual:  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html  This can be overridden in your makefile in various ways if you change `MAKEFLAGS`.  For example what does the `AM_MAKEFLAGS` variable expand to?  Does your makefile set `MAKEFLAGS` anywhere?  Etc.

Comment: Ah. AM_MAKEFLAGS may well not be MAKEFLAGS - But thanks MAKEFLAGS is the clue that might help me understand what is wrong. I believe AM_MAKEFLAGS is something from automake, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It definitely is (all `AM_` variables are, typically).  But it might be resetting things.  You should look at the output of your build and see what the actual `make` command line is that's invoked by this rule.  Also, you can add something like `+env | grep MAKEFLAGS` to this recipe to see what the value of `MAKEFLAGS` is when commands in this recipe are invoked.

Comment: Hmm only 1 mention of MAKEFLAGS - a read - in the automake generated Makefile, and no setting of AM_MAKEFLAGS. Yes I will add some prints for MAKEFLAGS in the launcher tomorrow.